# Contribution of the photovoltaic power plant to the short-circuit currents?

Tags: power, short-circuit, synchronous

What is the difference between the contribution of the photovoltaic power plant to the short-circuit currents comparing to situation with synchronous generator?

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking .... the usage of the words `contribution` and `situation` is unclear .... please give more detail or describe an example scenario

Comment: Note that PV arrays are inherently current-limited.

Comment: Like in a grid or at your house? Last time I checked they don't short either of those systems, bad things happen

Comment: @laptop2d my studies are based on connection of photo voltaic power plant to a distribution network(22kV medium voltage network), I want to know the impact of the photovoltaic power plant to the short circuit current compared to synchronous generator

Comment: I guess we should have read your mind

Answer (score 1):

The short circuit current of a grid tied  generation of power is the output impedance per unit of the supply and the amount of stored energy that follows a short that must be protected.

Z= Vnom/Isc = 8 to 12% per unit (pu) of maximum power depending on design and power range.

PV power uses Grid Tied Inverters (GTI) using SMPS and can turn off quickly by electronic current and temp sensing and may also have 100A fuses for 600V using only 50% typ. of rated current. 1MW is a common size PV for small utility farms.

Whereas a rotating generator has much more stored energy from inertia and generally much higher current per single generator so isolation protection must de designed differently for defined contactor break voltages and currents.

GTI’s although are current sources that track grid voltage, frequency and phase while regulating current to transfer power, the negative feedback of the current regulation raises its impedance to steady state passive load, this is never the case. Multiple GTI’s from different suppliers can cause harmonic circulating currents due to lower impedance at higher frequencies from output switching capacitance.  But generally they all go into step-up transformers designed differently for each application.